# Henyey method for interior parts of the star

Tags: star

Does there exist a code that implements Henyey method for interior parts of the star?

Comment: I find your question a bit confusing. Please rephrase it. Since Henyey was a astrophysicist it’s probable that he invented the method exactly for that purpose (though it may have other applications). As far as I know it is a standard method for solving models for the interior of stars.

Comment: Yes, my question is about a standard method for solving models for the interior of stars.

Comment: Yes, I think it is the standard method, at least for 1-dimensional models and at least when I did stellar models 25 years ago. The textbook I used was Kippenhahn and Weigert. It explains the method in detail. There is a second edition from 2012.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will read that chapter as soon as possible. And do you know about an implementation in whatever programming language? I would like to see how it work in praxis.

Comment: With a short search, I came across MESA. Unfortunately, I cannot even tell if it uses the Henyey method.

Comment: What is MESA, please?

Comment: @LukasAltmann: Just out of curiosity: What is the Heney method about? Maybe you could edit in a link into your question?